# Facebook: What is the graph api for subscribing user to the Facebook (webhook) for real time change

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am referring following links to the Facebook documentation for real time subscription.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks 
https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/videos/883648801749520/

For the page, the graph api v2.6/{page-id}/subscribed_apps is used for subscribing the page to the app.

I am looking for the graph api for subscribing user to the app for the real time changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for the graph api for subscribing user to the app for the real time changes.

There is no such endpoint.

For updates from users, you don’t need to create an individual subscription for every single one, like you need to do with pages.

You just do the general setup, that subscribes your app to updates for certain fields/edges of the user object. You then will get updates automatically for the users of your app, when a change on those happens (provided that the users gave your app the necessary permissions to read that kind of data.)

Comment: Thanks. Afaik, for object "page", we need either manage_pages or publish_pages permission for the Facebook app.
 
I tried to find the permission required for subscribing user in the facebook documentation but could not find.

What are the basic permission that the Facebook app required for the object user?
And will these permission effects on the number of fields we subscribe from the "User Subscription" page of Webhook tab of the Facebook App?

Comment: You need those permissions for a page, to be able to make the POST request to `/{page-id}/subscribed_apps`. _“I tried to find the permission required for subscribing user in the facebook documentation but could not find”_ – Again, that doesn’t exist.

Comment: Does it mean that we do not need any permission for the user object?

Comment: You need the normal permissions that are required to read the data you want.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering if the callback_url server at our end is down due to some reason and if there are changes in page and user profile, will facebook server send the updates when the server is up?

Comment: If there is no Graph API endpoint for subscribing user, how would de de-subscribe the user?

Comment: You wouldn’t. Once you create a subscription for your app for changes on user fields, you will get those updates for all users of your app, until they remove your app or at least the permission(s) required for your app to access that data in the first place.

Comment: Ok. I agree. But what if our application want to control which users to unsubscribe? We have a kind of logic where if the end users license to our application ends, we want to unsubscribe that user form our end using some api.

Comment: You can not unsubscribe from what did not require a subscription in the first place. The most you can do, is remove all permissions the user has granted to your app - but that won’t stop them from logging in and granting those permissions again. “Ignoring” the updates for certain users on your end might be the only option.